# AWS Public/Private subnet not accessible to internet with NAT setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat, subnet

I've already created the NAT device as instructed by AWS site. Disabled source checking. Create Security Group to allow proxy (in public subnet) to access the internet via 0.0.0.0/0. But still cannot access the internet. The NAT device however managed to access internet.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: I would consider using the VPC wizard to create a VPC with public subnet and private subnet, then dig in and see what it has created in terms of routing, NAT, and IGW.

Comment: Also see http://serverfault.com/questions/496736/cant-connect-to-ec2-instance-in-vpc-amazon-aws?rq=1.

Comment: @jarmod noted. i will try the VPC wizard first and check what's missing from my current setup.

Comment: -- unfortunately, the account has reached its maximum number of addresses limit to create new VPC. =(

Comment: FYI you can open a support case to increase account limits, like number of VPCs per region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **NAT server** is required for routing traffic from a Private Subnet to the Internet. This is because the private subnet (intentionally) does not have a direct connection to the Internet.

Amazon EC2 instances in the **Public Subnet** will not use the NAT. They will go directly through the Internet Gateway. The fact that your NAT can access the Internet suggests that this has been configured correctly.

If you have an EC2 instance in your private subnet that cannot communicate with the Internet, check the **Route Table entries** associated with your private subnet. The Route Table for your private subnet(s) should be different to the Route Table associated with the public subnet(s).

If necessary, add an entry to the Route Table associated with your private subnet to route traffic destined for `0.0.0.0/0` to the NAT server. The resulting destination entry will look like `eni-abcd1234 / i-1234abcd`. This means the Internet traffic is being routed to the Elastic Network Interface (ENI) on the NAT instance.

Comment: hi @john-rotenstein, i have setup my route table entries as follows:

Internet Gateway
10.0.0.0/16 | local
0.0.0.0/0 | igw-xxxxxxxx

Nat Server
10.0.0.0/16 | local
0.0.0.0/0 | eni-xxxxxxxx / i-yyyyyyyy

Comment: ok, i managed to get the public subnet workings. but my private subnet is still not accessible to internet. Associate private subnet to NAT Server router table also didn't allowed it to go to internet. =(

Comment: To debug the outwards connection from Private subnet -> NAT -> Internet, start by logging into the NAT and check whether it has Internet connectivity. Then, check the inbound Security Group on the NAT to ensure that it is allowing inbound traffic from the Private Subnet. Then check that the Route Table for the Private Subnet is pointing to the NAT, and that the Route Table is associated to the Private Subnet.

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT!** Make sure you are creating NAT server using NAT-Image from **Community AMI** category and look for '`amzn-ami-vpc-nat`'.

I'm accepting @john-rotenstein answer because it provides clear info on building the public/private network.

To summarise:

pre-condition: You've already setup the Public/Private subnet accordingly and NAT server is placed in Public subnet.

1. Build NAT server from NAT-image in Community AMIs
2. Create Security Group to allows instances from public/private to access to/from the NAT server

And you're done!